# Looking for a different proof of: $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ basis $\Rightarrow v_1,\ldots,v_r$ minimal minimal generating set

Tags: linear-algebra

I already found a simple proof for

$v_1,\ldots,v_r \in V$ basis $\Rightarrow v_1,\ldots,v_r$ minimal minimal generating set of $V$

by contradiction (suppose you can remove a $v_i$ and it's still a minimal minimal generating set, then you get linear depending vectors)

Now my question: Is there an other way to proove the statement from above, perhaps by using a different method?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof might go this way:

If $S$ is a proper subset of $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ of size $s$, then $span(S)$ is an $s$ dimensional vector subspace of $V$. Since $s=\dim(S)<\dim(V)=r$, it follows that $span(S)\neq V$, so $S$ does not generate $V$. Hence no proper subset of $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ generates $V$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a way with determinants you can think of?

Comment: Determinants would help you prove linear independence of $r$ length $r$ vectors, but they wouldn't say anything about the span directly. I could have overlooked something though... you'll have to let me in on your idea, if you think you see a way.